# Redundant appearance of the same language in App

Tags: swift, xcode

After installing my app on a device it shows the following four languages:
[image: Languages]

As you can see there is two times Deutsch ("German") as an available language.

But this is how it looks like in XCode:

[image: XCode-Languages]

I wonder why there is this entry "Deutsch (Deutschland)" in my app because it doesn't appear in XCode. Maybe it has to do with the fact that I changed the development language to German? Or where else can I set the available languages for my app?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it in deed by changing the development language back to "English" and deactivating Base Internationalization.